# Which plane figure has the minimal mean distance between two points on its perimeter, if all figures have the same area?

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose you have a plane figure, and you select (independently) two random points $A$ and $B$ on its perimeter, in polar coordinates, uniformly sampling angles $\theta_A, \theta_B$ and deriving the corresponding $\rho$ (constant for a circle, [like this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-polar-equation-for-a-square-if-any) for a square, etc).
You measure the Euclidean distance $d_{AB}$ between $A$ and $B$.
You repeat this many times, and plot the distribution of $d_{AB}$.

I tried this with a circle of radius $R = 1$, and the square with the same area (i.e. with side $R \sqrt{\pi}$), sampling 2000 points (1000 pairs).

Here are the resulting distributions and plots.
For the circle:

[image]
[image]

For the square:

[image]
[image]

The shapes of the distributions are quite puzzling to me (and it would actually be interesting to know how one could obtain them).

But the main question I have in mind is:

> **assuming equal areas, what plane figure would have the minimal mean distance?**

I would be tempted to think it's the circle, not sure why, but I just wanted to check if this had been already addressed / if you can point me to posts or websites discussing this.

Here is the `R` script I used to run the simulations.

```
# Number of pairs of points to sample
N = 1000

# Distance between two random points on the perimeter of a circle of radius R

R = 1

set.seed(12123)
theta <- runif(2 * N, 0, 2 * pi)
x <- R * cos(theta)
y <- R * sin(theta)
x1 <- x[1:N]
y1 <- y[1:N]
x2 <- x[(N + 1):(2 * N)]
y2 <- y[(N + 1):(2 * N)]
ds <- sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
hist(ds)
plot(x, y, pch = 16, cex = 0.1, asp = 1)
segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, col = ceiling(10*ds/max(ds)) )

# Distance between two random points on the perimeter of a square of side L

L = sqrt(pi) * R

set.seed(12123)
theta <- runif(2 * N, 0, 2 * pi)
R <- pmin(L/abs(cos(theta)), L/abs(sin(theta)), na.rm = TRUE) / 2
x <- R * cos(theta)
y <- R * sin(theta)
x1 <- x[1:N]
y1 <- y[1:N]
x2 <- x[(N + 1):(2 * N)]
y2 <- y[(N + 1):(2 * N)]
ds <- sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
hist(ds)
plot(x, y, pch = 16, cex = 0.1, asp = 1)
segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, col = ceiling(10*ds/max(ds)))
```

---

**EDIT** - adding the general parametric equations for sampling points on the perimeter or regular polygons with $N$ sides, based on uniformly distributed angles $\theta$:

$\left[ x=-{{R\,\left(\sin \left({{N\,\vartheta+2\,\pi}\over{
 N}}\right)-\sin \left({{N\,\vartheta-2\,\pi}\over{N}}\right)\right)
 }\over{2\,\left(\sin \left({{2\,\pi\,\left \lceil {{N\,\vartheta
 }\over{2\,\pi}} \right \rceil-N\,\vartheta-2\,\pi}\over{N}}\right)-
 \sin \left({{2\,\pi\,\left \lceil {{N\,\vartheta}\over{2\,\pi}}
  \right \rceil-N\,\vartheta}\over{N}}\right)\right)}} , y={{R\,
 \left(\cos \left({{N\,\vartheta+2\,\pi}\over{N}}\right)-\cos \left(
 {{N\,\vartheta-2\,\pi}\over{N}}\right)\right)}\over{2\,\left(\sin 
 \left({{2\,\pi\,\left \lceil {{N\,\vartheta}\over{2\,\pi}}
  \right \rceil-N\,\vartheta-2\,\pi}\over{N}}\right)-\sin \left({{2\,
 \pi\,\left \lceil {{N\,\vartheta}\over{2\,\pi}} \right \rceil-N\,
 \vartheta}\over{N}}\right)\right)}} \right] $

Comment: I think you need to add additional conditions, for example that the origin is contains within the plane figure - otherwise I would expect (intuitively) that putting the figure very very far from the origin would reduce the mean distance (and also make it so that most angles would not intersect the figure at all). Nice question though!

Comment: For a circle it's easy: $${d\theta\over ds}={1\over\sqrt{1-s^2/4}}\quad\text{and}\quad\bar s={4\over\pi}.$$

Comment: @Ant : indeed, thanks, I was thinking that the figure's 'centre' should be in the origin, only I did not know how to define the 'centre'. BTW I also found an error in my R script, there should be a factor of 1/2. I will correct the original post. With that correction, the distribution for the square has almost the same mean as the one for the circle(!). I did not expect that...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca : thanks; could you please point me to some literature describing how you derived this result?

Comment: In a unit circle you can fix a point at $A=(1,0)$ while the other varies at $B=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Hence $AB=2\sin(\theta/2)$ and $$\bar s={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} s(\theta)d\theta={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} 2\sin{\theta\over2}d\theta.$$

Comment: And for a square, a numerical integration gives $\bar s\approx 1.27408$.

Comment: Quite surprisingly, in the case of an equilateral triangle I got $\bar s\approx 1.27057$, less than for the circle.

Comment: It is indeed surprising. In my initial (vague) idea, I was thinking what shape a floor of a building should have to ensure that, wherever people are placed in it, they must walk on average the shortest distance to meet one another. Then I thought it would be too complicated to use the whole area, and imagined that the result would be the same if they were only placed on the perimeter. So yes, it is quite striking, to me at least, that many different figures of the same area give so close results. Perhaps it's not the average that I should be looking at though, maybe the median or mode... hmm

Comment: @user6376297 The problem is in the way you chose to select your random points. If you choose them uniformly on the perimeter length, instead of using the angles, I think you'd find quite different results. And probably that would be a better model for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a figure composed by four concentric circle arcs, two with radius $R$ and angle $\alpha$, the other two with radius $r<R$ and angle $\pi-\alpha$ (see diagram below). Take two points at random on its perimeter, $A$ and $B$, as described in the question (that is, selecting two angles uniformly, with vertex at the center).

If both points lie on the arcs of radius $R$, which happens with probability $(\alpha/\pi)^2$, then $AB\le2R$. If both points lie on the arcs of radius $r$, which happens with probability $(1-\alpha/\pi)^2$, then $AB\le2r$. If a point lies on the small arcs and the other on the large arc, which happens with probability $2(\alpha/\pi)(1-\alpha/\pi)$, then $AB\le(r+R)$. For the average length $\bar s$ of $AB$ we have then,
setting $x=\alpha/\pi$:
$$
\bar s\le x^2\cdot2R+(1-x)^2\cdot2r+2x(1-x)(r+R),
$$
that is:
$$
\bar s\le 2Rx+2r(1-x).
$$
If we want the figure to have area $\pi$, then:
$$
x\pi R^2+(1-x)\pi r^2=\pi,
$$
that is:
$$
R=\sqrt{1-(1-x)r^2\over x}.
$$
Inserting this into the inequality for $\bar s$ we get:
$$
\bar s\le 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-(1-x)r^2}+2r(1-x).
$$
For $x\to0$ we have then $\bar s\le2r$, and taking $r$ sufficiently small, we can make $\bar s$ as little as we please.

[image]

Comment: Thank you; I accepted the answer, although in the meantime I took your advice and derived the simple PDF for the circle ($PDF(D) = \frac 2 {\pi} \frac 1 {\sqrt {4 R^2 - D^2}}$) by fixing A and making B vary; much less sophisticated than this, which is what is within my reach as a non-expert. It fits the histogram from the R script, which is reassuring :) I haven't yet checked what the square's or the triangle's one would look like, but as you did numerical integration, I sort of assume they have no analytical PDF's(?).

Comment: @user6376297 The expression for $s(\theta)$ can be found quite readily as a piecewise function, but Mathematica cannot find an explicit exact result for the integral, hence I used the numerical integration engine in Mathematica.